# Vertically split DIV with scrollable content

Tags: html, css

```
+------------------+   <-- container - should not be stretched by its contents
|+----------------+|
||               |||
||               |||   <-- main div - as big as container minus footer
||               |||                  if content overflows, scrollbar appear
||               |||
||   scrollbar-> H||
||               H||
||               |||
|+----------------+|
|+----------------+|   <-- footer - stretched by its contents (button) to
||  [button]      ||                minimal needed height
|+----------------+|
+------------------+
```

.

The container may not have static size, thus solution "just calculate the height of main div" is not an option (without JS of course)

HTML5, no backward compatibility needed.

Comment: Are you planning for the container to have the height of the viewport? (For example the height of the Browser window)

Comment: No. If it ware I already found solutions using position:fixed , but it is included in another complex layout. (there comes in mind "dirty" solution using iframe... but "dirty")

Comment: You say you dont want to specify the height, and it should not take the height of the content and neither the height of the viewport. **But what height should the container take?**

Comment: Actually, Iframe has a specified height

Comment: The container would either have constant height or relative height (percentage of height of parent element).

Answer (score 2):

In CSS3 you can use

```
height: calc(100% - 60px);
```

that 60px can represent the height of the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
/* css */

<style>
    .container{
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .main{
        position: relative;
        height: calc{100% - 10%};
        width: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    .footer{
        position: relative;
        height: 10%;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<!-- html -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="main">
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go; using just html/flexbox:

You will notice that on the footer div when the `<p>` tag is added the div scales to a max-height of 30% and forces the main div to overflow the content again.

Should work without a static container height/width, guess it depends on parent container.

First: with minimal content

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.container{
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    }
.main{
    width:100%;
    background-color:blue;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .main p{
        color:white;
    }
.footer{
    max-height:30%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:red;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="main">
    <p>Trump2016</p><p>Trump2016</p><p>Trump2016</p><p>Trump2016</p>
    <p>Trump2016</p><p>Trump2016</p><p>Trump2016</p><p>Trump2016</p>
    <p>Trump2016</p><p>Trump2016</p><p>Trump2016</p><p>Trump2016</p>
    </div>
<div class="footer">
    <span>Trump2016</span>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Second: With added content (Showing container wills scale and force main div up).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.container{
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    }
.main{
    width:100%;
    background-color:blue;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .main p{
        color:white;
    }
.footer{
    max-height:30%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:red;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="main">
    <p>Trump2016</p><p>Trump2016</p><p>Trump2016</p><p>Trump2016</p>
    <p>Trump2016</p><p>Trump2016</p><p>Trump2016</p><p>Trump2016</p>
    <p>Trump2016</p><p>Trump2016</p><p>Trump2016</p><p>Trump2016</p>
    </div>
<div class="footer">
    <span>Trump2016</span>
    <p>Trump2016</p>
  

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This post contains answer I was looking for, but, uh, was that not so hidden election advertising needed?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps you.

I have use `height: 100vh` for `.container` and pulled `.footer` up by minus margin.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.footer {
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -50px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  footer
</div>
```